# When I upload excel with updated products with variants comes error (exceeded 2 calls per second for api client) in shopify Api

Tags: php, api, shopify

When I upload  excel with updated products with variants comes error  (exceeded 2 calls per second for api client)  in shopify Api.

Like I have 1200 products and respective products have different variantd 1 ,2 3 etc.

when i will update that excel and then try to call api then some variant update but some are not update and give error
==>exceeded 2 calls per second for api client

so Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is selft explanatory. It means you are exceeding the Shopify API call limit. More information on rate limitation is available on [Shopify Website](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/api-call-limit). It says

> The API call limit operates using a leaky bucket algorithm as a
>   controller. The bucket empties at a leak rate of two calls per second,
>   which means that apps averaging two calls per second avoid bucket
>   errors.

To do so, you need to implement rate limiting in your application. As the PHP tag suggests you are using API via PHP, you can have a look at

> [Shopify PHP](https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify)

It has a function **checkApiCallLimit** that ensures that your application does not exceed API rate limit.

```
$shopify = new PHPShopify\ShopifySDK($config);
```

Now any calls you make using shopify object, will respect the API rate limits. You can check the read me of linked library for more information.

Comment: I have updated the PHP library link and sample code in detail is available in read me.